# Get all neighbors of cell in array without out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make an ArrayList out of all the cells that neighbor a given cell in an array. Currently, my code works for any cell that does not have neighbors in the last row or right-most column. If it does have neighbors in these, I get the error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3"

Here's my code:

```
public ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbors(int row, int col) {
        ArrayList<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++) {
            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++) {
                if (!(r == row && c == col)) {
                    if ((c >= 0 && r >= 0) && (c <= (col + 1) && r <= (row + 1))) {
                        neighbors.add(landscape[r][c]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
```

Getting the neighbors of cell (1, 1) in a 2x2 grid like this one

0 0 0

0 0 0

0 1 1

returns: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] (Works correctly)

but if I look for the neighbors of any cell in row/col 2, I get the error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bounds check is wrong.

```java
c >= 0 && r >= 0 && r < landscape.length && c < landscape[r].length
```

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing. Thank you!!!